# Can i attach multiple attachments in one HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, http, servlets

For example, i would like to download one zip file and one csv file in one response. Is there any way other than compressing these two files in one zip file.

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thank you for your answer. Save me a lot of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although ServletResponse is not meant to do this, we could programmatically tweak it to send multiple files, which all client browsers except IE seems to handle properly. A sample code snippet is given below.

```
response.setContentType("multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=END");
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
out.println("--END");
for(File f:files){
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
      BufferedInputStream fif = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      int data = 0;
      out.println("--END");
      while ((data = fif.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(data);
      }
      fif.close();
      out.println("--END");
      out.flush();
}
out.flush();
out.println("--END--");
out.close();
```

This will not work in IE browsers.
N.B - Try Catch blocks not included

Comment: I have never seen this before. How do browser know the startIdx-endIdx of each file? First file start is idx=0 but how many bytes before next file is started? Should there be written multipart boundary lines?

Comment: Yes, there should be boundary lines (answer edited) written into the OutputStream which the browser intercepts and process.

Comment: You mean 'boundary=END' will be automatically intercepted by browser(except IE) and separated those file correctly?

Comment: Yes it does. I tweaked a webapp that I am working on to test this in firefox and chromium.

Answer (score 1):

Code developed by Jason Hunter to handle servlet request and response having multiple parts has been the defacto since years. You can find it at [servlets.com](http://www.servlets.com/cos/)

Answer (score 0):

No you can not do that. The reason is that whenever you want to sent any data in request you use steam available in request and retrive this data using `request.getRequestParameter("streamParamName").getInputStream()`, also please make a note if you have already consumed this stream once you will not be able to get it again.

The example mentioned above is a tweak that google also uses in sending multipart email with multiple attachments. To achieve that they define boundaries for each attachment and client have to take care of these boundaries while retrieving this information and rendering it.